# How do you use Python xpath to get information from webpage?

Tags: python, xpath

I have this problem with a simple xpath, I can't figure out why it's not working.
I copied the function from a working function, and i seriously don't have a clue why this doesn't work.
I read several tutorials and have a working function in another script, but this function doesn't do what I want. It should get some strings from the webpage, but I just get empty variables.

```
def getWeather():
  try:
    page = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=wetter&oq=wetter&ie=UTF-8')
  except:
     print('URL not reachable')

  tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
  #print( tree )

  weatherInfo = tree.xpath('//span[@id="wob_dc"]/text()')
  tempInfo = tree.xpath('//span[@id="wob_tm"]/text()')
  windInfo = tree.xpath('//span[@id="wob_ws"]/text()')

  print (weatherInfo) # empty

  r = str(weatherInfo) + " " + str(tempInfo) + " " + str(windInfo)

  return r
```

Can you give any advice?

Comment: I think you should go with `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about `headers` in your `requests`. This sample works for me:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

def getWeather():
  try:
    page = requests.get(
      'https://www.google.com/search?q=wetter&oq=wetter&ie=UTF-8',
      headers={
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
      }
    )
  except:
     print('URL not reachable')

  tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
  #print( tree )

  weatherInfo = tree.xpath('//span[@id="wob_dc"]/text()')
  tempInfo = tree.xpath('//span[@id="wob_tm"]/text()')
  windInfo = tree.xpath('//span[@id="wob_ws"]/text()')

  print (weatherInfo) # empty

  r = str(weatherInfo) + " " + str(tempInfo) + " " + str(windInfo)

  return r

getWeather()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Google. Their servers does not get rentable pages. So this question is not for python, but for a web-developers.
Version of non-web-developer(me): server creates page with weather, then sends you according your location and then deletes this. If you aren't from German, you get another page.
Problem isn't in xpath, but in request.

P.S.: I checked this code on my own with another link and it works.

Comment: Thank you, check other answer, it's the request. If you send header, you get a proper page.